# Store CMTime in CoreData?

Tags: iphone, core-data, avfoundation, cmtime

Sorry if this been answered before, but i can't find an answer here.

How do I store a CMTime value using CoreData?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert it to a dictionary and store the dictionary representation.

[CMTimeCopyAsDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CMTimeMakeFromDictionary) and [CMTimeMakeFromDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CMTimeMakeFromDictionary)

Comment: This sounds very interesting, will look into it tomorrow before I approve your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: How do you save dictionary representation in coredata?

Comment: @Or.Ron, check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562676/best-practice-array-dictionary-as-a-core-data-entity-attribute