# Convert a NSString into a NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsarray

I received data from a JSON web service and converted it to an NSArray.  I've saved the NSArray in my database for retrieval at a later date.  The data in the database looks like this:

```
(
        {
        ResponseCount = 2;
        ResponseTotal = 8;
    },
        {
        ResponseCount = 6;
        ResponseTotal = 8;
    }
)
```

Now I'm at the point where I want to take that data and turn it back into an NSArray.  I try doing something along the lines of

```
NSArray *responseArray = self.CoreDataTable.ResponseArray; //NSString value
```

or

```
NSArray *responseArray = (NSArray *) self.CoreDataTable.ResponseArray; //NSString value
```

But when this runs, the NSArray comes back with no objects in it.  Any ideas what is wrong?

---

Code to clarify data saving process.

```
CoreDataTable *coreDataTable = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CoreDataTable" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
coreDataTable.CategoryName = [d objectForKey: @"CategoryName"];
coreDataTable.ResponseArray = [d objectForKey: @"ResponseArray"];
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

Comment: are you using jsonkit or not?

Comment: You say “I've saved the NSArray in my database”.  Show us the code that saves it.

Comment: Good question.  The JSON from my web service is consumed using the iOS native NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: Updated the question to show the save for Rob

Comment: json kits hadels itself all the things, one thing which confusing me is that your data is not in array form, replace "(" with "[" and ")" with "]", it might work, check this hack...

Comment: Try using NSMutableArray.

Comment: Why not just store the raw JSON and then when you read it convert to NSArray using NSJSONSerialization?

Comment: I found that in Core Data, you can store an array as a "Transformable" data attribute rather than a string.  When you get the data back from the database, it is an NSArray and you can just loop through it.  Check here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562676/best-practice-array-dictionary-as-a-core-data-entity-attribute