# saving array of entities in coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, magicalrecord

I'm using magical record for working with coredata.
   how to save group of entities in model.

For saving a single object i used following code

```
StoryData *storyDataEntity=[StoryData MR_createInContext:localContext];
storyDataEntity.stories=storyData;
storyDataEntity.categoryType=categoryType;
storyDataEntity.timeStamp=[NSDate date];

[localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success,NSError *error)
 {
     if (success) {

         }
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"error:%@",[error localizedDescription]);
         }

     }
 }];
```

how to save group of entities i.e., more than one entity at a time.
I have array of stories i want to store them as an individual entity.

Comment: return to nsarray object

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that:

```
for (NSString *oneStoryData in yourArray) //yourArray is your array of stories
{
    StoryData *storyDataEntity=[StoryData MR_createInContext:localContext];
    storyDataEntity.stories= oneStoryData;
    storyDataEntity.categoryType=categoryType;
    storyDataEntity.timeStamp=[NSDate date];
}

[localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success,NSError *error)
 {
     if (success) {

         }
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"error:%@",[error localizedDescription]);
         }

     }
 }];
```

Also remember that StoryData is not an NSObject, it is a NSManagedObject.

**From Apple documentation**:

NSManagedObject is a generic class that implements all the basic behavior required of a Core Data model object.  **It is not possible to use instances of direct subclasses of NSObject (or any other class not inheriting from NSManagedObject) with a managed object context.** You may create custom subclasses of NSManagedObject, although this is not always required. If no custom logic is needed, a complete object graph can be formed with NSManagedObject instances.

What is the object inside your NSArray? A NSString or what?

If your array have StoryData entities, then this is your problem, how are you creating these entities? With [[StoryData alloc]init] ?

Then inside the for you can do something like:

```
for (StoryData *oneStoryData in yourArray) //yourArray is your array of stories
{
    StoryData *storyDataEntity=[StoryData MR_createInContext:localContext];
    storyDataEntity.property1 = oneStoryData.property1;
    storyDataEntity.property2 = oneStoryData.property2;
}
```

**EDIT**

Check this tutorial if you really want to save a whole NSArray/NSMutableArray in Core Data:

- [How to save a NSArray/NSMutableArray in Core Data](https://coderwall.com/p/mx_wmq)

Comment: can i store array of storyDataEntities in model

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1562725/1381708. However, for what the hell you want to store an Array of entities?

Comment: There's no need to log in the completion handler. MagicalRecord will log everything for you if you turn on logging

Comment: how to store array of emtities in coredata @ Gabriel.Massana

Comment: finally i have done in following way                              for (int i=0;i<[articles count];i++) {
  Article *article=[articles objectAtIndex:i];
  ArticleData *articleDataEntity=[ArticleData MR_createInContext:localContext];
        articleDataEntity.artcle=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:article];
        articleDataEntity.articleURL=article.article_url;
        articleDataEntity.categoryType=categoryType;
        articleDataEntity.articleType=@"main_article";
        [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        //[articlesData addObject:articleDataEntity];
    }