# Store an Array attribute in the Data Base

Tags: ios, swift, xcdatamodel

I have an attribute in my entity that should store multiple Int.
This is how the recieved JSON from the API looks like

```
 {
    "type": “KsCell”,
    “id”: 23,
    “allowedSize”: [1,2],
},
```

How can I declare/store this in the xcdatamodeld?

this is a list of attribute I can choose from, there is no array

[image]

Comment: this should be an array type

Comment: Which one is the array type? I tried Transformable but it's not working

Comment: you can convert array value to string while inserting into coredata and while fetching just convert again in array thats d only option you can do in this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "native" array or dictionary type in Core Data. You can store an NSArray or an NSDictionary as a transformable attribute. This will use the NSCoding to serialize the array or dictionary to an NSData attribute (and appropriately deserialize it upon access). - [src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1562725/3977988)

So, possible solution might be using of Transformable type.

As an expample, you can declare it in your NSManagedObject as:

```
@NSManaged var allowedSizes: [NSNumber]
```

and assign your parsed ints array from json

```
myObject!.allowedSizes = allowedSizeArray //[1,2]
```

Another solution is to use NSKeyedArchiver to convert your array into NSData.

```
let allowedSizes = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(allowedSizeArray) // NSData
```