# Core Data - To Many relationship - Table bindings

Tags: core-data, cocoa-bindings

I have a `NSTableView` with bindings.
Each row of the table is a Core Data Entity named `Entry`.

An `Entry` can have several `CustomValue`. Each `CustomValue` should be displayed in its own column in the Table.

I had 2 choices to model this in Core Data:

- **Choice 1**: Either model a dictionary as a Transformable, where the key is the column name & the value is the CustomValue.
- **Choice 2**: Either use a To-Many relation ship Entry <-->> CustomValue <--> key & value where key is a `Column` entity.

I chose the second solution based on this: [Best practice? - Array/Dictionary as a Core Data Entity Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562676/best-practice-array-dictionary-as-a-core-data-entity-attribute)

BUT my problem is : **with Choice 2, how can I bind the data to the column**?
With Choice 1, I could do something like this:

`textField.bind(NSBindingName.value, to: cellView, withKeyPath: "objectValue.myDictionary.\(tableColumn!.identifier.rawValue).value", options: nil)`

I'm currently stuck, I need to map a binding to something that would allow me to search for the proper value based on the key.

Any idea? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Idea A: What if `myDictionary` is a dictionary property calculated from `customValues`?

Comment: Idea B: Use datasource and/or delegate methods in combination with bindings.

Comment: Idea C: Don't use bindings with this table view.

Comment: Those are great ides, thanks! I tried Idea A but had problems with KVO notifications and was not comfortable going further. Idea B crossed my mind too but I was 'afraid' of the added complexity for sorting and maintaining the arrayController in parallel. Idea C added also a lot of work. I finally came back to Choice 1 because of the simplicity of the implementation compared to idea A, B & C. All in all, I think Idea A is the solution to this problem.