# Save Array of Strings to CoreData

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

I am trying to save an array of 6 strings to CoreData, like this:

```
     let imageUrls = ["image-url....", "image-url....", ..., "image-url"]
```

I have tried all methods stated in [How to save Array to CoreData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825604/how-to-save-array-to-coredata) and in [Best practice? - Array/Dictionary as a Core Data Entity Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562676/best-practice-array-dictionary-as-a-core-data-entity-attribute?noredirect=1&lq=1) without success.

This is the method I am trying to do.

Inside my .xcdatamodeld, I have declared:
imageUrl as a Transformable, see picture in link (couldn't attach it to the post, I'm sorry for that!): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VJey55oD9KhOy1KDy59h8PweMMQnaK2-/view?usp=sharing

Inside my NSManagedObject class I have

```
    @objc(Entity)
    public class Entity: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var imageUrls: [String]?
    ....
```

This is how I create the entity before saving it to CoreData:

```
    entity.imageUrls = ["test", "test", "test"]
```

When I try to fetch the imageUrls, the fetched entity.imageUrls is equal to nil. I don't understand this. The expected results is the same array I saved to CoreData.

**ANSWERED by Joakim Danielson**

Comment: Did you set the custom class to `[String]` in your model for the attribute?

Comment: Yes I did, forgot to mention that!

Comment: Maybe you need to clean and rebuild your project. I just created a simple test project and it worked fine using Transformable and setting a custom class

Comment: I forgot that I had to clean CoreData of all the nil objects.... It worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, @CoderOgden I'm having this exact problem. I tried cleaning the build folder and rebuilding but still the same result. Could you explain it a bit further how you fixed this?

Answer (score 12):

My suggestion is to encode/decode the array to JSON and use a computed property. From the Swift perspective this is probably more efficient than a `transformable` attribute which bridges the array to the Objective-C runtime and uses heavier `NSCoding`.

```
@NSManaged public var imageUrls: String

var urls : [String] {
    get {
        let data = Data(imageUrls.utf8)
        return (try? JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data)) ?? []
    }
    set {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue),
            let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { imageUrls = "" }
        imageUrls = string
    }
}
```

Another benefit is that a JSON string is searchable

Comment: The searchability is a good point. Thanks for the perspective.

Comment: The Transformable is also searchable. So, this argument is invalid.

Answer (score 6):

check the attachement below for declration in ".xcdatamodelId" file. After that declare  below line in CoreDataProperties.swift file

```
@NSManaged public var thumbnail: [String]?
```

Now, we can initialised string array into thumnail variable.[image: Declaration variable in xcdatamodelID file]

Comment: Why Array<Any> and not Array<String>?

Comment: we can use Array<String> .It will also work.I just take Array<Any> so I don't need to update model everytime.

Comment: For my case, I have to use non-optional type

Comment: Also, set `NSSecureUnarchiveFromData` to Value Transformer (it was renamed to just "Transformer"). Otherwise, you may get this runtime warning: `'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to save it to the core data as String and split the array with a seperator. The thing is that you have to be sure that the string will no include that seperator.

For example if you used the seperator ", " on saving your array to the core data you will have to save it like

```
coreData.arrayToStringValue = array.joined(separator: ", ")
```

and when you read your data you will have to read it like:

```
let arrayFromStringValue:[String] = coreDataValue.split(separator: ", ")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! That's a good idea, but it's a workaround. I might go for this solution, but I'm interested why mine doesn't work too...

Answer (score 1):

Change type of imageUrl to BinaryData, then convert your list to data and save.

```
let urls = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: imageUrls)
manageObject.setValue(urls, forKey: "imageUrls")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

I found [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian)'s answer very helpful. I Used the same idea, But in a different way. Giving my code hoping that it may help.

- Select the Type of the attribute that you want to store the array as String

[image]

// save to core data

```
var quizManagedObject : [NSManagedObject] = []

func save(question: String, answers: [String]) {

    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(answers),
    let answersEncodedString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return }

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Quiz", in: managedContext)!
    let quiz = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

    quiz.setValue(question, forKeyPath: "question")
    quiz.setValue(answersEncodedString, forKeyPath: "answers")

    do {
        quizManagedObject.append(quiz)
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

// fetch from core data

```
func fetchCoreData() {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Quiz")

    do {
        quizManagedObject = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        for i in quizManagedObject {
            if let decodedAnswerString = i.value(forKey: "answers") as? String {
                let data = Data(decodedAnswerString.utf8)
                let answerArray = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data)
                let question = i.value(forKey: "question") as! String

                print("Q : ", question)
                print("A : ", answerArray ?? [""])
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your object is transformable without any custom class you might either want to cast it to `[NSObject]` and save it like that as it's the Transformable base-type. But you probably should make it `[String]` as the base class.

There are also no indication of you ever saving the data to `core data`? What you have displayed is just assigning a variable in a model. Which you really never should do as they should be `immutable` and not `mutable`.

Answer (score -6):

The following are the types of data, that we can store.

[image]

You cannot store array data. You need to convert into comma-separated strings. Then try to save it into coredata. And while you are fetching, you can convert it into `array`.