# Make a Core Data Array without relationships

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I just wanted to ask if is there a way to create a String Array in Core Data without using relationships because I kinda not like them it seems to complicated too me.

If it is a way which one?

Comment: What you are looking for is a transformable property or converting the array to json and storing it as a Data attribute, see for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57705721/9223839)

Comment: Thanks buddy you helped me!

Comment: Rather than *objective-c-ish* transformable in Swift I'd prefer to declare the attribute as `String` and create a computed property for the conversion from and to JSON with `Codable`. Another benefit is that a JSON **string** is searchable.

Comment: Yh I though of that too but while trying to do it I was encountering some problems when i fetched them so I wanted to try another way, thanks for the anser tho.