# How to store array of values in a Core Data Model in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am trying to build an app that saves what cars a user owns, and I want to use Core Data to save the car's attributes. I already have implemented the ability to store a single piece of data (like the car's name, manufacturer, year etc). However I want to also store an array of strings. Basically, my object model looks like this:

Name: String
Manufacturer: String
Year: String
Colour: String
features: [String, String, String]

How would I implement this last line which is an array? Previous research tells me to use transformable but I don't know how to

Thanks

I'm using Xcode 13.4 / 14 and SwiftUI

Comment: did you create NSManagedObjectSubClasses of your entity ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you mean `[String]`, I mean, a single array of String is that so?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703836/save-array-of-strings-to-coredata/57705721#57705721

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
You can create a new entity `Feature` in your Core Data model with a property `description: String`, and define a one-to-many relationship from Car to Feature, which will make it a child to `Car`.
Fetching cars will then give you access to the related features. Look for some Core Data examples on how to implement this.

**Option 2:**.
You can just add another property `features` to the `Car` entity in Core data model, which holds the feautures as ONE string separated by e.g. `,`.
Then just divide / concatenate to decode/code:

```
var features = "one,two,three"

// load
var featureArray: [String] = features.components(separatedBy: ",")

// change
featureArray.append("four")

// save
features = featureArray.joined(separator: ",")
```

Comment: go with 1 if you want to ever show a list of all features