# Swift - saving a dictionary to Core Data

Tags: swift, dictionary, core-data

As part of an API response for a particular object we receive the following:

```
"itemNotes" : {
        "disclaimer" : "some text here"
      },
```

However, `itemCaptions` can contain an indeterminate number and range of values, each with type `[String: String]`.

So within my data model I am setting this up as follows:

```
struct Item: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    ...
    let itemNotes: [String: String]?
    ...
}
```

This works fine, except that I need to be able to store instances of this model in core data but I am unsure how to go about this. I already have an `Item` entity but how can I set up a relationship to represent a dictionary item whose key could be anything?

Comment: This can be achieved by Transformable type in Core Data. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/handling_different_data_types_in_core_data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practice? - Array/Dictionary as a Core Data Entity Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562676/best-practice-array-dictionary-as-a-core-data-entity-attribute)

Comment: One option is to store the original json as a string attribute another one is to create an entity with two string attributes, key and value